# functions na.rv(T), na.omit, is.finite, etc. don't work for the mean of a column

Tags: r, mean, na

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a large df, dividing observations by Id and month and none of the answers I found work as I expect, sometimes they empty my sample and that's not useful.

If df is:

```
permno               company        amihud   illiq  MonthYr
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  1.389026403 1.625   1990-01
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  1.028968686 NA      1990-01
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  NA          NA      1990-01
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  NA          NA      1990-01
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  Inf         NA      1990-01
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  Inf         NA      1990-02
10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  0.891034483 NA      1990-02
10397   WERNER ENTERPRISES INC  0.443933917 NA      1990-01
10397   WERNER ENTERPRISES INC  0.255496848 NA      1990-01
10397   WERNER ENTERPRISES INC  0.891034483 NA      1990-02

structure(list(permno = c(10026L, 10026L, 10026L, 10026L, 10026L, 
10026L, 10397L, 10397L, 10397L, 10397L), date = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1/10/1990", 
"1/11/1990", "1/12/1990", "1/15/1990", "1/2/1990", "1/3/1990", 
"7/29/1998", "7/30/1998", "8/6/1998", "8/7/1998"), class = "factor"), 
    company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("J & J SNACK FOODS CORP", "WERNER ENTERPRISES INC"
    ), class = "factor"), price = c(11.75, 12.75, 13, 13, 12.375, 
    12.75, 12.25, 12.25, 10.75, 11.25), volume = c(36360L, 82710L, 
    22750L, 8574L, 40262L, 10150L, 25200L, 9000L, 333100L, 52200L
    ), amihud = c(1.389026403, 1.028968686, NA, Inf, Inf, 0.891034483, 
    0.255496848, NA, Inf, 0.891034483), illiq = c(1.625240831, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MonthYr = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1990-01", 
    "1990-02"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("permno", "date", 
"company", "price", "volume", "amihud", "illiq", "MonthYr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to calculate the Amihud measure (measures illiquidity in finance, therefore risk). In short: I need the mean per stock (permno) and per month of the variable 'amihud', which I will call 'illiq'.

I tried:

```
res <- smallcap %>%
        group_by(permno, MonthYr) %>%
        mean(amihud, na.rm=T) %>% 
        group_by(permno)
```

I don't know till what extent this is right, but every attempt for omitting or subsetting NA and Inf wasn't successful.

Expected result, regardless of the correctness of this example and without the need of the amihud variable:

```
permno               company    illiq   MonthYr
    10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  1.65    1990-01
    10026   J & J SNACK FOODS CORP  0.87    1990-02
    10397   WERNER ENTERPRISES INC  0.25    1990-01
    10397   WERNER ENTERPRISES INC  0.55    1990-02
```

I appreciate any tips you could give.

Comment: Please share your data in a way that allows easy import into an R session. `dput` is useful for that.

Comment: Could you please help me out to upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
#since you don't care about the Infs convert them to NAs
#so that they get removed at the mean function 
#since we have set na.rm=TRUE
df$amihud[df$amihud==Inf] <- NA

library(dplyr)
#you need to use summarise to calculate the means as below:
res <- df %>%
          select(permno, company, MonthYr, amihud) %>%
          group_by(permno, company, MonthYr) %>%
          summarise(illiq = mean(amihud, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
> res
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: permno, company

  permno                company MonthYr     illiq
1  10026 J & J SNACK FOODS CORP 1990-01 1.2089975
2  10026 J & J SNACK FOODS CORP 1990-02 0.8910345
3  10397 WERNER ENTERPRISES INC 1990-01 0.2554968
4  10397 WERNER ENTERPRISES INC 1990-02 0.8910345
```

P.S. the values in your expected output probably come from the full set since there is only one value for `10026 J & J SNACK FOODS CORP 1990-02` and that should also be the mean i.e. `0.8910345` and not `0.87` as in your output.

Comment: You certainly did, this lets me advance a lot in my research!